# console.timeEnd("start") not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

**I have multiple javascript files for my project & in one of them I am using this function**

abc.js

```
Initial.start = function(){
    console.time("Initial.start");
    // Rest of codes go here
    if(someCondition){
        $("someDomElement").trigger("click")
    }
    console.timeEnd("Initial.start")
}
```

xyz.js

```
function _xyz(){
    // code that will be executed on clickevent on that DOM element
}
```

This click event handler function is written in a different javascript file.
Now my problem is when this if condition is false console.timeEnd is successfully executing, but when it is true that _xyz() is also successfully executed but console.timeEnd("Initial.start") is no more printing the time. Any pointer will be appreciable. Thanks!

Comment: what is `console.start`? Where are you starting the "Initial" timer?

Comment: sorry for the mistake. Have edited the post

Comment: I think we really need to see ```someCondition``` and the body of ```_xyz``` to help you

Comment: Sounds like an exception is being thrown that stops the execution of your script.

Comment: I'm with @robertklep on this one, either an exception is being thrown or the event handler loops.

Comment: Or the event triggers a page change?

Comment: @robertklep page change doesn't actually stop the execution 
    start = function(){
             console.time('a');
             if(1==1){foo()}
             console.timeEnd('a');
         }, foo = function(){document.location.href = 'http://google.com'} still logs the time before switching pages

Comment: @DrunkWolf true, changing the page is not quick enough to not continue the test of the script.

Answer (score 0):

So it's probably one of 3 things (as discussed by me and robertklep in the comments)

```
start = function(){
        console.time('a');
        if(1==1){foo()}
        console.timeEnd('a');
    }
```

1) your event handler is throwing an exception.

```
foo = function(){return f.foo.bar}
```

2) your event handler is looping.

```
foo = function(){foo()}
```

3) the simplified code you provided is leaving out that you're actually returning a value.

```
start = function(){
        console.time('a');
        if(1==1){return foo()}
        console.timeEnd('a');
    }
foo = function(){return false;}
```